# Setting Data Grid View Cell back color now working

Tags: datagridview, format

I have done this on other DGV's but it is not working on this current project, why wont the color change. i even tried Inheratedstyle.

```
for (int i = 0; i < dgvRigs.RowCount; i++)
        {
            string strAim = null;
            strAim = dgvRigs.Rows[i].Cells[5].Value.ToString();
            if (strAim == "Y")
            {
               dgvRigs.Rows[i].Cells[5].Style.BackColor = Color.Red;
            }
        }
```

Comment: Is the `IF` condition `True` and so the `BackColor` line is executed at the iterations where it should? When you place your breakpoint(s) and debug? This is first thing to check and put into question as important information.

Comment: i put a break point on the Y and i go in to the proper step as needed but the color does not change on the screen.

Comment: And if you put breakpoint on the "}" line after the color assignment, is `BackColor` set to `Red` at reuired iterations? When you hover above the `BackColor`.

Comment: for instance if i = (row 4 and cells[5] = Y  I put a watch on dgvrigs.rows[4].cells[5].style.backcolor and i see it shows red. but the grid cell is still not red.

Comment: this is my watch data dgvrigs.row[1].cells[5].style.backcolor    "{name = 0, argb = (0,0,0,0)} (this row/cell = N so the backcolor should not be red     dgvrigs.row[2].cells[5].style.backcolor    "{name = RED, argb = (255,255,0,0)} (this row/cell = Y so the backcolor should be red